# How can you limit range of stat_function plots with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a figure to show different saturation levels and their effect on sampling dynamics for a talk using the following code:

```
max <- 2
decay <- function(x, k, C) {
    C * (1 - exp(-k*x))
}
require("ggplot2")
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x, colour = C)) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 0:max, C = factor(1)), fun = function(x) { decay(x, k=10, C=1e1) }) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 0:max, C = factor(2)), fun = function(x) { decay(x, k=10, C=1e2) }) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 0:max, C = factor(3)), fun = function(x) { decay(x, k=10, C=1e3) }) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 0:max, C = factor(4)), fun = function(x) { decay(x, k=10, C=1e4) }) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 0:max, C = factor(5)), fun = function(x) { decay(x, k=10, C=1e5) }) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 0:max, C = factor(6)), fun = function(x) { decay(x, k=10, C=1e6) }) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"), labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) + scale_colour_discrete(name=expression(paste(C, " value"))) + 
    ylab(label="count") + ylim(0, 100)
```

The intention is to show that for the high C value cases the curve will appear linear. However, the ylim prevents any curve from being shown where it has a value greater than the max for the ylim when I would expect it to merely truncate the curve at the max value.

How do I get the desired behaviou?

Comment: Isn't this the purpose of the 'xlim' and 'ylim' functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have noticed the difference between limiting the `scale`(using `scale_y_continuous(limits=...)`)
or limiting the coordinate space (using `coord_cartesian(ylim=...)`.

When you call `ylim` it uses the equivalent of `scale_y_continuous` and drops observations not in the range

The help for `ylim` and `xlim` describe this (and point to `coord_cartesian` as an alternative)

```
# here is your example rewritten
ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x=x,colour=C))  +
  lapply(1:6, function(y){
        stat_function(data = data.frame(x=0:max,C=factor(y)), 
            fun = function(x) decay(x,k=10, C = 10^y))) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"), 
                    labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) +   
scale_colour_discrete(name=expression(paste(C, " value"))) + 
ylab(label="count") +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,100))
```

Comment: Thank you, that clarified it perfectly. The extra code reduction was a nice touch.